# Missing trainable parameter when loading model from tensorflow hub

Tags: tensorflow-hub

I'm migrating our code from tensorflow 1 to tensorflow 2. One of the layers is embedding layer loaded as follows:

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1"
self.use_embed = hub.Module(model_url, trainable=False)
```

In Tensorflow 2 this will become

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
model_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3"
self.use_embed = hub.load(model_url)
```

[because](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/Module)

> The hub.Module API works for TF1 only. For TF2, switch to plain SavedModels and hub.load().

However, `load()` method does not support `trainable` parameter?

What has happened to this parameter and how can I apply it in Tensorflow 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Model Compatibility Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/model_compatibility#compatibility_of_tf2_savedmodel) mentions that the parameter has a different name for `hub.load()` and `hub.KerasLayer()`:

> Use either hub.load:
> m = hub.load(handle)
> outputs = m(inputs, training=is_training)

> or hub.KerasLayer:
> m =  hub.KerasLayer(handle, trainable=True)
> outputs = m(inputs)